# How to automate a test case which requires an overnight batch job to run?

Tags: automated-testing

The test scenario goes like this -

Change a value in config -> A job will execute at midnight -> config change will be update in system -> Verify that new config value is reflected.

Now how to wait for 24 hours for result verification.
Any strategy for this kind of test cases

Thanks

Comment: I'm confused.  Is this a production system or a test system this all happens on?  How much control do you have over the environment?

Answer (score 3):

Have the developers provide you with a way of triggering the scheduled task outside of its normal time slot.

Where I currently work this is provided as a webpage that has all of the possible scheduled tasks for a service, with buttons to trigger each one manually.

We use this page during our automated tests, and then observe the result.

We also do a manual check to make sure that the job itself has been scheduled correctly, e.g. it runs at midnight without being manually triggered.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the following approach:

- Find the code that performs the overnight update.
- Make sure it has good test coverage.
- For the code that depends on it, replace the actual calls with mock responses.
- For production ensure you have monitoring on the dependent service

Answer (score 0):

When there is no way to trigger the job yourself like its proposed in https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/38880/35888 you would need some kind of persistent memory. I could imaging a test making the change in the config and writing what was  changed in a database (or plain file). A second test would read the database and only perform the necessary checks if there is an entry and enough time has passed

Though this feels like a dumb workaround and not like the "right" way to do it.